# WPF Style for ToggleButton as Chevron - how to remove annoying thin lines

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

While trying to style a ToggleButton with a Chevron shape, i cannot get rid of the annoying thin lines which are rendered, which can be seen at the screenshot.

Can anyone help out here?

**Style:**

```
<Style x:Key="ChevronButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" >
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,-10,0" Height="30" ClipToBounds="True">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Path Grid.Column="0" Name="ChevronLeft" Data="M0,0 10,0 10,30 0,30 10,15" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" >
                            <Rectangle  Name="ChevronBack" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Name="ChevronText" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="10,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Path Grid.Column="2" Name="ChevronRight" Data="M0,0 10,15 0,30" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ChevronLeft" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Petrol}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ChevronBack" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Petrol}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ChevronRight" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Petrol}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ChevronText" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="ChevronLeft" Property="Fill" Value="DarkGray" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ChevronBack" Property="Fill" Value="DarkGray" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ChevronRight" Property="Fill" Value="DarkGray" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ChevronText" Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="ChevronText" Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theses artifacts should disappear when you set `UseLayoutRounding` or  `SnapsToDevicePixels` on the parent Grid:

```
<Grid UseLayoutRounding="True">
```

Or

```
<Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
```

Comment: I have added SnapsToDevicePixels="True" to all of the elements and it looks much better! Thank you, dude. You made my day. :)

Comment: It's sufficient to set it on the parent Grid, because child elements inherit the value - of both properties.